# Is there a way to "gem install" to only the development environment, or test?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Using `gem install`, how can I add a gem to only one particular environment, like development or test or production? As seen below:

```
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end
```

Comment: I don't believe so-gem install just installs, it knows nothing about environments. It's the loaders that decide what to load when a la Rails and the Gemfile groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this via `gem` as the `Gemfile` is used by Bundler.  However, since Bundler version 1.15.0 you can use `bundle add`:

```
bundle add web-console --group development
```

This will then add the following line to your `Gemfile`:

```ruby
gem "web-console", "~> 3.6", :group => [:development]
```